# How to reduce the range space of scrollbar to be different from the div height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I want to resize the space where the scrollbar moves.
I don't want it to affect how much I can scroll.
Look at the following pictures (my drawings) to better understand what I mean.

[image: This is what I have]

[image: This is what I want]

I'm using chrome so webkit is viable.

Thanks to all of your answers!

(P.S. I would love to have reduce the image size, yet I don't know how to! My apologies!).

Answer (score 0):

Without nesting another element and play with its height you could simply use a huge `border-bottom` and place a visible border around the element using the `outline` property, e.g.

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px #9bc solid;
  border-bottom: 50px transparent solid;
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVpwYo)

---

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the height of the scrollbar but you can redesign the scrollbar with -webkit-scrollbar like this:

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
        height: 10px;
        background: transparent;

    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #808080;
    }
```